# Can you use the Wish spell to duplicate a 9th-level spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, wish

In the description of the [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) spell, it states that:

> The basic use of this spell is to duplicate any other spell of 8th level or lower.

But it also states:

> You might be able to achieve something beyond the scope of the above examples.

Does this mean you can duplicate a 9th-level spell by suffering the stress?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Yes

You may attempt to do *anything* with this spell, but going outside the duplication of an 8th level or lower spell represents risk. The DM determines any potential result, but the stress will be a risk you'll definitely endure.